# Want VBA in excel to read very large CSV and create output file of a small subset of the CSV

Tags: vba, csv, excel

I have a csv file of 1.2 million records of text.  The alphanumeric fields are wrapped in quotation marks, the date/time or numeric fields are not.

For example
"Fred","Smith",01/07/1967,2,"7, The High Street","Anytown","Anycounty","LS1 7AA"

What I want do is write some VBA in Excel (more or less the only tool available to me that I am reasonably proficient in the use of) that reads the CSV record by record, performs a check (as it happens on the last field, the post code) and then outputs a small subset of the 1.2m records to a new output file.

I understand how to open the two files, read the record, do what I need to do with the data and write it out (I will just output the input record with a prefix denoting an exception type)

What I don't know is how to parse the CSV in VBA properly.  I can't do a simple text scan and search for commas as the text sometimes has commas in (hence why the text fields are text delimited)

Is there a fantastic command that would let me quicky get the data from the nth field in my record?

What I want is 
    s_work = field(s_input_record,5) where 5 is the field number in my CSV....

Many thanks,
C

Answer (score 8):

How about VBScript, though this would also work in Excel:

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'Note HDR=Yes, that is, first row contains field names '
'and FMT delimted, ie CSV '

strCon="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\Docs\;" _
& "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";"

cn.open strcon

'You would not need delimiters ('') if last field is numeric: '    
strSQL="SELECT FieldName1, FieldName2 INTO New.csv FROM Old.csv " _
& " WHERE LastFieldName='SomeTextValue'"

'Creates new csv file
cn.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: I've used a similiar technique to accomplish the same thing in the past

Comment: +1 this is the best solution for such a large dataset, I've done this with aggregated data in the past

Comment: @Fionnuala, I'm using your answer to read a CSV file into the memory. However, I am experiencing a 280 char limit as I pointed out in a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230062/excel-vba-reading-csv-file-with-large-multiline-values-using-adodb-with-jet-or-a   Did you experience such behavior and any idea how to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 8):

The following code should do the trick. I don't have Excel in front of me, so I haven't tested it, but the concept is sound.

If this ends up being too slow, we can look at ways to improve the efficiency.

```
Sub SelectSomeRecords()
    Dim testLine As String

    Open inputFileName For Input As #1
    Open outputFileName For Output As #2

    While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, testLine
        If RecordIsInteresting(testLine) Then
            Print #2, testLine
        End If
    Wend

    Close #1
    Close #2
End Sub

Function RecordIsInteresting(recordLine As String) As Boolean
    Dim lineItems(1 to 8) As String

    GetRecordItems(lineItems(), recordLine)

    ''// do your custom checking here:
    RecordIsInteresting = lineItems(8) = "LS1 7AA"
End Function

Sub GetRecordItems(items() As String, recordLine as String)
    Dim finishString as Boolean
    Dim itemString as String
    Dim itemIndex as Integer
    Dim charIndex as Long
    Dim inQuote as Boolean
    Dim testChar as String

    inQuote = False
    charIndex = 1
    itemIndex = 1
    itemString = ""
    finishString = False

    While charIndex <= Len(recordLine)
        testChar = Mid$(recordLine, charIndex, 1)

        finishString = False

        If inQuote Then
            If testChar = Chr$(34) Then
                inQuote = False
                finishString = True
                charIndex = charIndex + 1 ''// ignore the next comma
            Else
                itemString = itemString + testChar
            End If
        Else
            If testChar = Chr$(34) Then
                inQuote = True
            ElseIf testChar = "," Then
                finishString = True
            Else
                itemString = itemString + testChar
            End If
        End If

        If finishString Then
            items(itemIndex) = itemString
            itemString = ""
            itemIndex = itemIndex + 1
        End If

        charIndex = charIndex + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but `grep` (or one of the Windows equivalents) would really shine for this, e.g.,

```
grep -e <regex_filter> foo.csv > bar.csv
```

Comment: Windows variants of grep: WinGrep(http://www.wingrep.com/), PowerGrep(http://www.powergrep.com/), and GNU Grep for Windows(http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).

Comment: Given that grep is available in some form, and it's entire purpose is to print lines matching a regex, which seemed sufficient for the filtering mentioned in the question, it seemed like a natural fit.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following derivative of the code given above to successfully open an arbitrary csv file from VBA in Excel.

> Option Explicit
>   Public cn As Connection
>   Public Sub DoIt()
>   Dim strcon As String
>   Dim strsql As String
>   Dim rs As Recordset
>
> Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
>
> strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\bin\HomePlanet\;" _
>   & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";"
>
> cn.Open strcon
>
> strsql = "SELECT * FROM astuname.csv "
>   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
>   rs.Open strsql, cn
>   DoEvents ' pause here to inspect objects and properties
>   rs.Close
>   End Sub

The rs (recordset) has a collection of fields, with a Count property. Each field as a Type property.

You can reference the fields by sequence number ...

> Debug.Print rs.Fields(rs.Fields.Count - 1).Type

Is this sufficient?

If not, post the first several rows of the input file and I'll take it the rest of the way.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `Input #` statement in the Excel help

Sample usage would be:

```
Input #fnInput, s_Forename, s_Surname, dt_DOB, i_Something, s_Street, s_Town, s_County, s_Postcode
```

and then use the `Write #` statement to write matching records out again

The only issue might be that the date format in the output will end up as #1967-07-01# but this format is unambiguous unlike 01/07/1967 which would represent 1st July in the UK and 7th January in the US. If you need to preserve the formatting of the date then write it out as a string:

```
s_DOB = Format(dt_DOB, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 2):

Anything you can do a-row-at-a-time with vba in excel, you can do in access with vba; plus a lot more because it's a database rather than a spreadsheet. Is access unavailable to you?

It's a lot easier to deal with logical tables, records, and fields than logical worksheets, rows, and columns.

For input, why does the "/Data/Import External Data/Text/csv" not work? Is the input not truly portable csv?

Comment: 1.2 million rows is not going to work in Excel, however, data can be manipulated with ADO using the Jet engine, that is, the engine on which Access is based. Hence my reply.

Comment: ok - so to confirm - Access is not available? Anyway, if you can access Jet with ADO, you can also open an Access mdb database from within Excel with Excel VBA and store the data there - you wouldn't even need Access installed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at the Regular Expression library (you should see it in "Tools...References" as "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" or something very similar.

There are samples of both the Reg Exp and a fairly comprehensive character-by-character at this location: http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/c_ParseCSV.php. Note that the Regexp version is waaaay shorter!

Have fun...