# return csv file as recordset

Tags: excel, vba

I have an external program that exports data into CSV files. My users would like to have access to this data through a VBA function in excel. In order to do this, I thought about wrapping the CSV file read into a function that returns a ADODB.Recordset. My code is

```
Public Function getData(fileName As String) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim path As String
path = "C:\testDir\"
Dim cN As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
cN.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & path & ";" & _
               "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;""")
RS.ActiveConnection = cN
RS.Source = "select * from " & fileName
Set getData = RS
End Function
```

I am trying to call this function using

```
Dim a As ADODB.Recordset
Set a = getData("testFile.csv")
a.Open()
```

At this point, I get a compile error saying '=' expected. Could someone point me in the right direction on how I should call my function and loop through the data?

Comment: `a.Open` (without the parentheses).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/431546/190829

Comment: @TimWilliams - Could you retype your comment as an aswer so I can accept it?

Comment: @CP - you can just accept your own answer - no problem for me...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved it with some tweaks of my own along with input from Tim Williams. Here is the code for anyone else who might need help

```
Public Function getData(fileName As String) As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\testDir\"
    Dim cN As ADODB.Connection
    Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
    Set cN = new ADODB.Connection
    Set RS = new ADODB.Recordset
    cN.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                   "Data Source=" & path & ";" & _
                   "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;""")
    RS.ActiveConnection = cN
    RS.Source = "select * from " & fileName
    Set getData = RS

End Function
```

Now, the function can be called as

```
Dim a As ADODB.Recordset
Set a = getData("testFile.csv")
a.Open
MsgBox(a.GetString())
a.Close
```

Comment: How much better to parse the recordset inside the function and return a string or an array instead of having to open the recordset **OUTSIDE** of the function that creates it.

Comment: @JimmyPena - Arrays would definitely be cleaner than returning a record set. I have a second implementation of my function that converts the record set into an array but did not add it to the solution since it wasn't part of the original question. But I definitely like the arrays better

Comment: I agree, there should be a series of helper functions here.

Comment: Additionally, `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` was required instead of Jet