# VBA manipulate large csv file using SQL statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure if this question makes sense/is dumb or is not specific enough. Please advise.

I need to create an excel macro that will output part of a large csv file that meet a certain criteria.

For example, in the csv, there is a list of 20m or so phone numbers with other columns (city, gender, ...). I would like to have the user input those criteria and have outputted either a new csv file with the results or be in a new tab.

Is there a way query the csv file with pandas or SQL like statements ? Like `df[df[city] == 'CA']`.

I would like to be able to distribute this macro and so if it is possible to do without having to install some database.

If this is possible, how efficient/inefficient is this, as compared to installing a SQL database for example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use ADO to read the CSV file as a recordset.  That will allow you to then make use of the recordset's .Filter property to apply the user's filter.

This answer to another question shows how to open the file as a recordset:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11637197/9542263

You'll want to check on how memory intensive this is since you've indicated that your CSV file will be quite large.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a few options available to you.  Consider the following VBA code.

```
Sub TryThis()
Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim ReturnArray

Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String

DBPath = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\"

sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBPath & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited'"

Conn.Open sconnect
    sSQLSting = "SELECT * From CSV1.csv WHERE ID = 2"
    mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs
    'Close Recordset
    mrs.Close

Conn.Close

End Sub
```

File looks like this.

[image]

After the code runs, you get this.

[image]
Also, see the link below.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2017/02/12/loading-csvtext-files-with-more-than-a-million-rows-into-excel/

Finally, consider using Power Pivot, which is a free AddIn.

https://professor-excel.com/how-to-work-with-large-data-and-powerpivot/