# Modifying a CSV using Excel macros

Tags: excel, vba, csv, ms-word

I'm attempting to extract information from a CSV (**studentData.csv**) in Word. I've determined that due to some formatting from the database the CSV in question was made from, Word recognizes that there are n lines, but it is counting carriage returns *within the line itself* as one of the lines, resulting in me not actually reaching EOF.

i.e.: The following information is treated as two lines, thus throwing off my count.

```
All of this information
is stored in one cell
```

After some hours of different attempts, I resolved to write a script in a separate Excel workbook (**runMe.xlsm**) to format **studentData.csv**. Unfortunately, I've been hitting a wall; when I try to open the CSV as a workbook and retrieve the filename, it's returning **runMe.xlsm** instead. Below is my code:

```
Sub testingStuff()

    Dim r      'Rows that contain data
    Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, p As String

    'Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:="\...\studentData.csv", local:=True)

    p = Dir("\...\studentData.csv")
    Debug.Print p

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(p)
    Debug.Print wb.path & ": " & wb.Name  'checking the path

    Set sh = wb.Sheets(1)

    r = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("O:O"))

    Debug.Print wb.Name & ": " & sh.Name & ": " & r

End Sub
```

This my Immediate Window:

```
studentData.csv
\...\: runMe.xlsm
runMe.xlsm: Sheet1: 0
```

I'm not at all sure why it's returning the control file name - I can only assume that the code isn't recognizing the CSV as a workbook, so it's defaulting to **runMe.xlsm**.

*I should note that both the CSV and the xlsm file are in the same folder.*

So, how should I go about formatting this? I wrote a short macro:

```
    r = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("O:O"))

        With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            For i = 1 To r
               .Cells(i, 15).Value = Replace(.Cells(i, 15).Value, vbNewLine, "")
            Next
        End With
```

I just need a way to apply it. Or, do I not even have to bother formatting the CSV - can I get around this issue in Word?

Comment: I personally wouldn't even use Excel for this at all if you're just intending to pull data into Word - I'd use ADODB and just query for what you need. That avoids most of the potential pitfalls with auto-formatting that you can run into when you open a csv file in Excel.

Comment: I just looked that up - I'm definitely going to look into this as a potential solution. Unfortunately, I'm self taught in this arena and working with limited resources, so I'm trying to stick to the little I know and that's mostly VBA macros.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11637197/4088852) will be a good start.

Comment: Okay. I think I can make sense of that. Thanks for the assist! I'll take a dive into this.