# Excel reading .csv file incorrectly

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have posted this in the Microsoft Community Forum and have been directed here.

I am using VBA to open a .csv file programmatically.

The .csv file contains text, date and number fields/columns.

When this file is opened manually and not as part of the VBA routine, the date fields show the dates in the dd/mm/yyyy format with no text identifier (floating apostrophe) before the date text.

So a date of 1st May 22 is shown as 01/05/2022.

Below is a screen shot of the .csv file when opened manually - Note Columns I and J show the correct dates

[image]

The VBA process has been built to open this file when identified by the user using the 'Application.GetOpenFilename' function.

The file is then opened programmatically.

When I place a break in the code to view the opened file before it is queried, some dates do not reflect the dates when the .csv file is opened manually.

E.g. A date of 01/05/2022 is shown if the programmatically opened file as 05/01/2022

Basically, where the DAY and MONTH when swapped can represent a date value, they are swapped.

The code being used to 'get' the file containing the required data is below

```
***strEDFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select the file containing the Booking Data", "Select", False)

If strEDFile = "False" Then 
   MsgBox ("A file to import was not selected"), vbInformation, "NO SELECTION MADE" 

   Exit Sub 
   Else 
End If 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Application.Calculation = xlManual 

Set wbBD = ActiveWorkbook 

Set wsBD = wbBD.Sheets("Booking Data") 

Set rngBD = wsBD.Range("BD_Start") 

Set wbED = Application.Workbooks.Open(strEDFile) 

Set wsED = wbED.ActiveSheet***
```

When the file is opened via the above code, the days and months are swapped around in columns I and J - See image below

[image]

The solution is to save the .csv file as a .xlsx file before uploading via the VBA process, but this shouldn't need to be done.

Comment: Is the csv file in discussion `Tab` delimited, comma or some other delimiter? Does it contain data starting from A:A column? Do you have problems only with the `Date` format in columns I:J?  If so, it looks that your localization confuses Excel in terms of Date/Month. Excel tries guessing which the format to return... That's why I would suggest opening it using `OpenText`, formatting the respective columns `As Text` and then processing them to return the format you need.

Answer (score 1):

The way that the date is interpreted in a .csv file is dependant on the locale settings for Windows.

The way to work around it, is to use the **OpenText** method.
During the import set the format that is used for each column by using the **XlColumnDataType**.

Value - Name - Description
1 - xlGeneralFormat - General
2 - xlTextFormat - Text
4 - xlDMYFormat - DMY date format

In the example code below, all columns are imported as **Text** (2).
Except for the two date columns that are imported as dates in the **DMY** (4) locale format.

> If you are using Excel in Office365, I would recommend looking at PowerQuery (*Data - Get Data - From File - From Text/CSV*)  to import the data.

```
Sub Example()

    strEDFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select the file containing the Booking Data", "Select", False)
    
    If strEDFile = "False" Then
       MsgBox ("A file to import was not selected"), vbInformation, "NO SELECTION MADE"
    
       Exit Sub
       Else
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    
    Set wbBD = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Set wsBD = wbBD.Sheets("Booking Data")
    
    Set rngBD = wsBD.Range("BD_Start")
    
    Application.Workbooks.OpenText _
            Filename:=strEDFile, _
            StartRow:=1, _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            Comma:=True, _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2), Array(6, 2), Array(7, 2), Array(8, 2), _
            Array(9, 4), Array(10, 4))
'Use the OpenText method to open the .csv file

    Set wbED = ActiveWorkbook
'Set a reference to the opened workbook
'OpenText does not return a reference

    Set wsED = wbED.ActiveSheet

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem where we need to separate the Data Value from what we seen on the screen - saving the file as a .xlsx is only adding an unnecessary step. You could try opening the CSV using a SQL query, then at least you will get the value returned as a Date and you can do what you like with it.  See here for an example of how to do that [return csv file as recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635526/return-csv-file-as-recordset/11637197#11637197)
Alternatively, read the CSV line by line