# Split large CSV file with header into multiple CSV files for every nth row with a header

Tags: csv, excel, vbscript, vba

I have a large CSV file that I would like to split into multiple CSV files. I've tried numerous VBS scripts, but I cannot seem to get this.

This script does some of what I want but does not save them as CSV files:

```
Sub Split()
Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim rCells As Range
Dim strName As String
Dim lLoop As Long, lCopy As Long
Dim wbNew As Workbook

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set rLastCell = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    For lLoop = 1 To rLastCell.Row Step 35
        lCopy = lCopy + 1
        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
        .Range(.Cells(lLoop, 1), .Cells(lLoop + 35, .Columns.Count)).EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        wbNew.Close SaveChanges:=True, Filename:="Inventory_" & lLoop + 34
    Next lLoop
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Before Closing the workbook, save it as CSV: `wbNew.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Temp\MyCSV.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV`. After that, you can close the workbook with `SaveChanges:=False`.

Comment: You can get more control with a recordset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427488/want-vba-in-excel-to-read-very-large-csv-and-create-output-file-of-a-small-subse/427511#427511

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added a saveas line to your code to specify the file format, you should be all set

```
Sub Split()
Dim rLastCell As range
Dim rCells As range
Dim strName As String
Dim lLoop As Long, lCopy As Long
Dim wbNew As Workbook

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set rLastCell = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    For lLoop = 2 To rLastCell.Row Step 35
        lCopy = lCopy + 1
        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
        .Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=wbNew.Sheets(1).range("A1")
        .range(.Cells(lLoop, 1), .Cells(lLoop + 35, .Columns.Count)).EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=wbNew.Sheets(1).range("A2")
        wbNew.SaveAs FileName:="Inventory_" & format(lLoop + 34,"0000") & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
        wbNew.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next lLoop
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is close. Is there a way to keep the first line on every subsequent CSV file? Also, is there a way to make the file name have 4 numbers every time? Currently, it creates Inventory_35.csv, Inventory 135.csv, Inventory 1235.csv. Can we change it so that it always has 4 numbers? So, Inventory_0035.csv, Inventory 0135.csv, Inventory 1235.csv, et. al.

Comment: Also, I would like to be able to make it semi-colon seperated instead of comma separated. So is there a way to set the sperator?

Comment: Change the regional settings on your computer before saving (then change them back). Region and Language \ Additional Settings \ List separator.

Comment: Yes, I've done that (and haven't changed it back), but the VBA is saving them as comma separated instead of semi-colon separated??

Comment: I changed my code for your first question. For the comma vs semi-column, are the commas in your excel sheet to start with?

Comment: No, I am dealing with a large CSV file that I save as a *.xlsm file to run the Macro.

Comment: and your current list separator is the semi-column, as in the French regional settings

Comment: Yes, it is. My list separator is set to semicolon.

Comment: Even if I change my settings to French, the Macro still makes it comma-separated instead of semi-colon separated.

Comment: I think that this will help: [Semi-Colon Separated](http://logbuffer.wordpress.com/2010/10/19/vba-save-excel-table-as-csv-semicolon-delimited/)

Comment: That didn't work. To test, I checked Region and Language \ Additional Settings \ List separator. Then open a SEMI-COLON separated file in Excel, separates nicely. Then open a COMMA separated file in Excel, stays in Column A.

Comment: To further test, I create a file and save as CSV then open in Notepad to see it semicolon separated.

Comment: Excel will only split your csv properly if they're delimited by the list separator in your regional settings. To force the split otherwise, you'll need to use text to columns.

Comment: No, the culprit is wbNew.Close SaveChanges:=True. It is removing the semicolons and changing them to commas. Changing that line to wbNew.Close SaveChanges:=False solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

maxRows = 35
i = 0
n = 0

Set out = Nothing
Set csv = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\PATH\TO\your.csv", ForReading)
header = csv.ReadLine

Do Until csv.AtEndOfStream
  If i = 0 Then
    If Not out Is Nothing Then out.Close
    Set out = fso.OpenTextFile("out_" & Right("00" & n, 2) & ".csv", ForWriting)
    out.WriteLine(header)
    n = n + 1
  End If
  out.WriteLine(csv.ReadLine)
  i = (i + 1) Mod maxRows
Loop

csv.Close    
If Not out Is Nothing Then out.Close
```

Comment: I agree. No need to involve Excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
'In O365 Excel the OpenTextFile statement should be CreateTextFile in order to
'create a new file.

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

maxRows = 35
i = 0
n = 0

Set out = Nothing
Set csv = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\PATH\TO\your.csv", ForReading)
header = csv.ReadLine

Do Until csv.AtEndOfStream
  If i = 0 Then
    If Not out Is Nothing Then out.Close
    Set out = fso.CreateTextFile("out_" & Right("00" & n, 2) & ".csv", ForWriting)
    out.WriteLine(header)
    n = n + 1
  End If
  out.WriteLine(csv.ReadLine)
  i = (i + 1) Mod maxRows
Loop

csv.Close    
If Not out Is Nothing Then out.Close
```